# JSP, JSTL, Bean Inheritance, and PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans, propertynotfoundexception

I have two JavaBeans.

1. User
2. Engineer

Engineer extends User.

User contains this property:

```
public String getName() { return name; }
```

My JSP contains:

```
<c:forEach var="engineer" items="${engineers}" >
    <c:out value="${engineer.Name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

The exception being thrown is:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Name' not found on type Engineer
```

Is this because JSTL won't find the inherited properties? Will I need to explicitly declare another `getName` property on Engineer even though it inherits `getName` from User?

Comment: Did you try `${engineer.name}`? lower case instead?

Comment: I feel dumb. Apparently `${engineer.name}` will uppercase the first letter of the property and add "get". I'm off to read the JavaBeans specification. Please put this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Cool! Just added it as an answer. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
${engineer.name}
```

the `name` should be lower case.